# How to align all equalities?

Tags: align

I am a newbie here and I got stuck in the following situation. Let me type the portion first

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_2(u_iu_{i+1})&=&\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    4 & \hbox{for~odd~$i$} \\
    3 & \hbox{for~even~$i$,}
  \end{array}
\right.\\[.2cm]
f_2(v_mv_1)&=&5,\\
f_2(u_mu_1)&=&5,\\

for $2\leq i\leq m-1,$

f_2(v_iu_i)&=&5,\\
f_2(v_mu_m)&=&1,\\
f_2(v_1u_1)&=&2.
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

My problem is: I want the sentence "for $2\leq i\leq m-1,$" at the extreme left while all other equality signs shown above should be aligned. But I falied to maintained that. Please someone help me on it.

P.S. Please feel free to edit the above if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A first comment: you shouldn't use `eqnarray`: it yields bad spacings and is obsolete. Use one of the `amsmath` environments instead (`align,aligned`, &c.)

Answer (score 7):

I propose two solutions, based on `align*`, and the `cases*` environment from `mathtools` (it is like the standard `cases`, except the second column is typeset in text mode):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f_2(u_iu_{i+1}) & =\begin{cases*}
  4 & for odd $ i $ \\
  3 & for even $ i $, \end{cases*} \\
  f_2(v_mv_1) & = 5, \\
  \text{for $2\leq i\leq m-1$,}
  \quad f_2(v_iu_i) & = 5, \\
  f_2(v_mu_m) & = 1, \\
  f_2(v_1u_1) & = 2.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  f_2(u_iu_{i+1})&=\begin{cases*}
  4 & for odd $ i $\\
  3 & for even $ i $,
  \end{cases*} \\
  f_2(v_mv_1)&= 5,\\
  f_2(v_iu_i) & = \begin{cases*}5 & for $ 2\leq i\leq m-1 $, \\
  1 & for $ i = m$,\\
  2 & for $ i = 1$. \end{cases*}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can combine several of these branches so I'd go for something like this:

[image]

Rather than `eqnarray` I recommend using the `align*` from the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. There is also a `cases` environment for typesetting piece-wise functions and a `\text{...}` command for writing text inside equations. Putting these together, here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
      f_2(u_iu_j)&=\begin{cases}
        3,&\text{if $i$ is odd and }j=i+1,\\
        4,&\text{if $i$ is even and }j=i+1,\\
        5,&\text{if $i=m$ and }j=1,
      \end{cases}\\
      f_2(v_iu_i)&=\begin{cases}
        1,&\text{if }i=m,\\
        2,&\text{if }i=1,\\
        5,&\text{if }2 \leq i \leq m-1.
      \end{cases}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In plain TeX, it should be done by this:

```
$$\eqalignno{
  f_2(u_i u_{i+1}) &= \cases{4 & for odd $i$, \cr 3 & for even $i$,} \cr
  f_2(v_m v_1) &= 5, \cr
  f_2(u_m u_1) &= 5, \cr
\noalign{\hbox{for $2 \leq i \leq m-1$,}}
  f_2(v_i u_i) &= 5, \cr
  f_2(v_m u_m) &= 1, \cr
  f_2(v_1 u_1) &= 2.
}$$

\bye
```